# String "none" in the small description - Luma Theme

Tags: luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

I noticed this string in the small description. This "nessuno" string is seen only in Italian view while for other views it does not go out. How can I remove it? What is this string?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `description` attribute title label is nessuno for Italian store view.

Go to Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product and click on `description` attribute code. Check under `Manage Labels` for Italy store view.

Comment: I tryied for both, short description and normal description but don't happen nothing. Are there other solutions even through files modification? Link: http://www.avalonitalia.com/pouf-poltrona-sacco-piccola-bag-jive-tessuto-tecnico-antistrappo-imbottito-avalon.html